# Realmのコレクション要素に対する検索条件の記述について

Tags: swift, ios, realm

```
class Dog: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var age = 0
    let owners = LinkingObjects(fromType: Person.self, property: "dogs")
}
class Person: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    let dogs = List<Dog>()
}
```

追加したデータ

```
realm.add(Person(value: ["AAA", [["taro", 1], ["pochi", 6]]]))  
realm.add(Person(value: ["BBB", [["kuro", 1], ["hachi", 6]]]))  
realm.add(Person(value: ["CCC", [["taro", 6], ["pochi", 6]]]))  
realm.add(Person(value: ["DDD", [["kuro", 6], ["chibi", 6]]]))
```

たとえば、上記のモデルとデータで。

dog.nameが"taro" かつdog.ageが5以下のpersonsを得るには
どのような検索を記述すればよいのでしょうか？

Dogを検索し、ownerをたどってpersonを得ることはできました。

```
let dogs = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter(NSPredicate(format: "name = 'taro' && age <= 5"))
for dog in dogs {
    for p in dog.owners {
        NSLog(p.name)
    }
}
```

Personを検索して同様の結果を得る記述方法はあるでしょうか？

Comment: 最終的に必要なオブジェクトは`Department`ですか、それとも`Person`ですか？`Person`オブジェクトが欲しいなら`Person`クラスには`Department`の関連はないので`Department`のプロパティを条件に検索することはできません。`Department`のプロパティで`Person`を検索するなら`Person`クラスに`Department`の関連を持たせる必要があります。`Department`を検索して、そのプロパティである`persons`を得るということであれば、おっしゃっている条件をそのままクエリにすると`realm.objects(Department.self).filter("name = %@ && any persons.dogs.name = %@ && any persons.dogs.age <= %d", "tokyo", "taro", 5)`となります。

Comment: 欲しいのはPersonです。それでは、先ずDepertmentオブジェクトからPersonオブジェクトを検索して、得たPersonに対し検索(filter)する、手順でいいのでしょうか？

Comment: そうなりますけど、素直に検索できるようにデータモデルを直したほうがいいんじゃないですか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。そうですね。モデルを変更する方がいいですね。では、Depertmentオブジェクトを検索する場合はどのようになるのでしょうか？　私はコレクションの検索を理解できていないようです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let results = realm.objects(Person.self)
            .filter("any dogs.name = %@ && any dogs.age <= %d", "taro", 5)
```

「dog.nameが"taro" かつdog.ageが5以下」というクエリはこのように書きます。

`any`はAggregate Operationsというコレクションの各要素が条件に一致するかどうかを調べる演算子です。

RealmのクエリはNSPredicateのAPIをそのまま使っているだけなので、NSPredicateについて学べばわかります。より詳しく知りたい場合は下記のアップル公式ドキュメントをご覧ください。

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215891

Comment: いろいろ試してみました。そして「kuroかpochiで3才以下のperson」のつもりで次のような条件を書きました。結果は'BBB'のみを期待しているのですが、'AAA'も検索されてしまいます。INはどうのように解釈すればいいのでしょうか？　よろしければ教えて下さい。　let persons = realm.objects(Person.self).filter(NSPredicate(format: "any dogs.name IN %@ && any dogs.age <= %d", ["kuro", "pochi"], 3 ))

Comment: INは複数項目のORなので書かれている条件とクエリは一致しているように見えます。​'AAA'や'BBB'と言われても我々には分からないのと、別の種類の質問なので改めて検索対象のデータがどうなっているのかと一緒に別の質問を書いてください。

Comment: 編集された最初の投稿にデータは書いてありましたね。失礼しました。これは正しい動作です。AAAはpochiと５歳以下のtaroを持っているので条件に一致しています。クエリの`dogs.name`と`dogs.age`の`dog`要素が同じものという条件を足すにはサブクエリを使います。コメントでは解説しにくいのでやはり新しい質問として投稿してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。新しい質問を投稿させて頂きます。